# SAS Drive to Motherboard Connector

Tags: motherboard, connector, sas

So I ordered a motherboard and a hard disk. Upon their arrival I noticed that there are no cables to connect the SAS drive to the motherboard. What cables do I need?

(The motherboard supports SAS drives through the the LSI 2308 SAS controller.)

(I was unable to find anything conclusive in any manual or guide.)

Comment: What's the make/model of the motherboard in question?  What kind/how many SAS connectors are on the board?  Dose the chassis you're installing this into have a mid- or back-plane for the drives?

Comment: Hey @techie007 The motherboard is a SuperMicro X9DR7-LN4F with 8 SAS2 ports. The case (non-rack-mountable) is the Coolermaster Cosmos II, there doesn't seem to be a back-plane... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use SAS drives, without an expander or a backplane, then you'll need a "forward breakout cable".

Sepcifically you'll want a "SFF-8087 to SFF-8482 Forward SAS Breakout Cable"

Here's some to look at for reference, [here](http://www.hywireonline.com/isas-7382.html) and [here](http://www.ncix.ca/products/?sku=34960) and directly from LSI [here](http://store.lsi.com/store.cfm/Internal_Multi-Lane_Cables/All_Cables/CBL-SAS8087OCF-06M/).

[image: LSI SAS forward breakout cable]

> Connects the controller’s SFF-8087 Multi-lane connector(s) to up to
>   four individual SAS or SATA drives; includes individual drive power
>   connectors

Comment: Thanks a lot, so this could be used to connect the motherboard to up to 4 Seagate Constellation ES drives (http://www.provantage.com/seagate-st2000nm0001~7SEGS27Y.htm)? Thanks again.

Comment: Can't see any reason why it wouldn't. :)